# How to filter the plugin store by price

Tags: craft3, plugins

We have a tight budget for a new Craft 3 site. How can the paid plugins be filtered from the store, so we can review only the free ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you can not. But a bit of PHP and the plugin store's API url shows you the list of plugins of which the first edition is free (or go to [this page](https://nilsenpaul.nl/free-craft-plugins)):

```
<?php

 $perPage = 100;
 $page = 1;

 $done = false;
 while (!$done) {
   $url = 'https://api.craftcms.com/v1/plugin-store/plugins?perPage=' . $perPage . '&page=' . $page . '&orderBy=name&direction=asc';
   $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

   if (isset($response->plugins) && !empty($response->plugins)) {
     foreach ($response->plugins as $plugin) {
       if ($plugin->editions[0]->price === null) {
         echo '<strong>' . $plugin->name . '</strong><br />';
         echo $plugin->shortDescription . '<br />';
         echo '<a href="https://plugins.craftcms.com/' . $plugin->handle . '" target="_blank">Show me more</a><br /><br />';
       }
     }
   }

   if ($response->totalResults <= ($perPage * ($page))) {
     $done = true;
   }

   $page++;
 }
```

Comment: Well done, Paul.

Comment: Thanks, Brad :)